# How to receive an alert when a pod autoscales in OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus

I am running OpenShift 4.6.20 and would like to get a Prometheus notification when a workload exceeds a percentage of the MaxPods value ie: 75% in Horizontal Pod Autoscalers. I have tried looking for that metric within Prometheus but I cannot find it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)? Using the `kube-state-metrics` your Prometheus will have the following HPA [metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/horizontalpodautoscaler-metrics.md), then you're able to calculate your HPA usage based the following metrics:

- `kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replica` - The HPA maximum defined replicas
- `kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_status_desired_replicas` - The HPA desired number of replicas

---

**NOTE**

`kube-state-metrics` rename the `hpa` metrics in release `v2.0.0`, make sure you're viewing the documentation based on your deployed release of `kube-state-metrics`

---